# Bxslider: reload on multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a page with multiple bxSlider and, when the user clicks a button, every slider needs to be reloaded with new images.
Everything works fine when I have a single slider, but it stops working with more than one slider.
When the `reloadSlider()` method is called I get a `"$(...).reloadSlider is not a function"` error.

Since the sliders are dynamically created (I don't know how many of them I'll have on the page), I can't create every single slider on like this:

```
var slider1 = $('#slider1').bxSlider();
var slider2 = $('#slider2').bxSlider();
...
```

But I need to create them all at once with:

```
$('.slider').bxSlider();
```

But when I try to call `$('.slider').reloadSlider()`, I get the error above.

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and i come up with this.
You can initially load all sliders in array like:

```
var sliders = [];
$('.sliders').each(function(i,item){
  var slider;
  slider.$(this).bxSlider();
  sliders[i] = slider;
});
```

Then, you can loop through and reload each

```
$(sliders).each(function(){
    this.reloadSlider();
});
```

Comment: Well, I solved destroying all sliders and recreating them. Not very elegant, but it works... I'll give your solution a try, though. Thank you.

Comment: What if the place you call bxSlider() is not the same place you reload it? How do I get the object to call reloadSlider() from the $('.sliders') element?

Comment: There is an error in your code. Instead "sliders.$(this)" is "sliders = $(this)"

Answer (score 1):

```
var sliders = $('.slider').map(function() {
  return $(this).bxSlider();
});

sliders.each(function() {
  this.reloadSlider();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.

The slider was initialized and attached to an object:

`someObj.slider = $('.slider').bxSlider({...})`.

Later from a different method calling
`someObj.slider.reloadSlider()` didn't work but `someObj.slider.data('bxSlider').reloadSlider()` did.

Hope this helps..